# Vishnusahastranam : From which shlok should we start reading

Tags: vishnu-sahasranama

If we are not doing nyasas, shapvimochan vidhi then from which shlok should we start reading.

Some places suggest to start from यस्य स्मरण मात्रेण  others suggest शुक्लाम्बरधरं विष्णु.

Please advice.